Payment method not showing in checkout Magento 2.4.6
I have some problem with payment method in the checkout.
If I add a payment method in the backend, the front end not showing what I add. Its always shwoing “Credit/Debit Card Secure Payment”
It doesn't matter if I've chosen bank transfer, paypal, or check/money order.
It only shows “Credit/Debit Card Secure Payment” even if this is not selected.
Have try to clear all payment info, upgrade function, and make all new static content.
Always the same :(
enter image description here


Please share the backend screenshot where you enable other payment methods.

Facing the same issue - did you find a solution?
